# Nestjs + Passport: Prevent user 1 to access information of user 2

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, nestjs, nestjs-passport

How can I prevent user 1 to access information of user 2 using passport in a Nesjs app ?

I already have 2 strategies:

- the local strategy which validate a user with email/password. The route protected by this strategy return a jwt token.
- the jwt strategy which validate the given jwt token.

Now, I want to restrict access to routes such as `users/:id` to jwt token which actually have the same *userId* encrypted.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**

I was mixing **Authentication** and **Authorization**: what I want to achieve is about authorization, once the user has been authenticated.

I had to use Guard:

*own.guard.ts*

```
@Injectable()
export class OwnGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return req.user.id === req.params.id;
  }
}
```

Then use it in my route:

```
@Get(':id')
@UseGuards(OwnGuard)
async get(@Param('id') id: string) {
  return await this.usersService.get(id);
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

What I did was to create a third strategy based on the jwt one:

```
@Injectable()
export class OwnStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'own') {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: SECRET,
      passReqToCallback: true
    });
  }

  async validate(req: Request, payload: { sub: string }) {
    if (req.params.id !== payload.sub) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return { userId: payload.sub };
  }
}
```

Note how I pass the custom name 'own' as second parameter of `PassportStrategy` to differentiate it from the 'jwt' one. Its guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class OwnAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('own') {}
```

This works but I wonder if it is the **good way** of doing it...

What if later I want to able user modification for admin users ?

Should I create a forth strategy which check if `role === Role.ADMIN || req.params.id === payload.sub` ?

I think I'm missing something. There should be a way to create a strategy which validate only the jwt, another one only the *userId*, another one only the role, and combine them as I want when applying guards to my routes.

Answer (score 1):

same case. you can use `handleRequest` method in guard.

here you can access user auth and req, then doing validation for resource appropriate. check out my code

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
        return super.canActivate(context);
    }

    handleRequest(err, user, info, context: ExecutionContext) {
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest<Request>();
        const params = request.params;
        if (user.id !== +params.id) {
            throw new ForbiddenException();
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

look more here https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#extending-guards